# Reading JSON with JQuery : Field Names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select, drop-down-menu

I have a json payload like below;

```
{ "ABW": "Aruba", "AFG": "Afghanistan", "AGO": "Angola" }
```

As you see, it will have all countries. I can read a JSON payload as it is mentioned here;

http://webhole.net/2009/11/28/how-to-read-json-with-javascript/

One problem here is that, how am I going to read the Country Codes here? They will change for every each value.

My goal here is to assign the Country code to value property of the option and country name to text of the option in a select list.

Comment: Just to save you some debugging time: The required delimiter for all strings (including key names) is ", not “. As quoted, that JSON is invalid, so if you were copying and pasting from your actual source...

Comment: @TJCrowder, i had that issue when i was trying to make the fiddle. I had to convert all the `"`

Comment: Why not display format your json like this [{"Code":"ABW","Name":"Aruba"},{"Code":"AFG","Name":"Afghanistan"}]

Comment: @Amin -- see comment to @RobotWoods' answer...

Comment: @TJCrowder nice touch there. thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need for any jQuery. Good ol' plain javascript to the rescue:

```
var countries = { "ABW": "Aruba", "AFG": "Afghanistan", "AGO": "Angola" };

for(code in countries){
    alert("code: " + code + "\n" + "country: " + countries[code]);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2adKZ/

Comment: This seems to be simple and straight-forward solution.

Comment: oops, deleted my comment asking how it knew which piece to return (I'd read up in the interim). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When JQuery uses the each function the index is made up of the name of the first bit of information 
So in { "ABW": "Aruba", "AFG": "Afghanistan", "AGO": "Angola" }
the Index for the first object will be "ABW" and the value "Aruba"

```
var countries = { "ABW": "Aruba", "AFG": "Afghanistan", "AGO": "Angola" }
$.each( countries , function(index) {
    var code = index;
    var country = countries[index] 
})
```

or

```
$.each( countries , function(index) {
    var code = index;
    var country = this;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the response structure? to (maybe):

`{"countries":[{"code":"ABW","name":"Aruba"},{"code:"AFG","name":"Afghanistan"}]}`

Comment: Why? There's no reason to, it just adds overhead. (Not my DV, btw, though I can see it...)

Comment: If you're interested: *[Myths and realities of `for..in`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)*

Comment: @TJ, thanks! Whenever I've had potentially unknown labels I just went to an array (as it seems many do based on the other answers and comments) so I'm sure `for in` will help many more than just myself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make it an an array of objects, and then loop through each?

```
{"results" : [
     {countryCode : "ABW",
      country : "Aruba"},
     {countryCode : "AFG",
      country : "Afghanistan"}]
```

Then loop through each object in your array to get the country code and country name.

Comment: see comment to @RobotWoods' answer

Comment: ah, forgot about the for in notation for JS  :P